# Is there a way to copy the same material to different objects at once?

Tags: materials, scripting

Is there a way to copy the same material to different objects at once?

[image]

I mean on an object that already has a material applied to it,

[image]

I want to copy 'material.003' to all selected objects.
Instead, I want the applied materials to be added without changing

Answer (score 1):

Select all Object with "shift + click" that you want to give the same material.
After that click this Icon in the Material field and chose copy to selected

[image]

Comment: You can also use the shortcut CTRL+L > Link materials

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I already know that function :[ Can you read my revised article again?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, I think there is a language barrier and you may be using a translator. Maybe it would be easier if you used images or screenshots to present us what you want and how this solution doesn't work instead ?